# parse data from website

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a new function for excel, where basically the user enters a Serialvalue into a Cell and then in another Cell they can type `=GetPartNumber(SerialValue)` and it would return the part number associated with that serial value.

In order to get the part number i have to do a search on an internal intranet site, I've got this part working, its able to send the serial and then click the submit button and the site reloads with the correct data, its just the parsing of the results i am stuck at..

```
Public Function GetPartNumber(UnitSerialNumber)

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
.MenuBar = 0
.Toolbar = 0
.StatusBar = 0
.Navigate " https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/basicUnitData.faces"
.Visible = 0

End With

'wait a while until IE as finished to load
Do While ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

' This bit submits the Serial to the site and clicks the go button
With ie.document.all
    .Item("unitDataSearchForm:serialNumber").Value = UnitSerialNumber
End With
ie.document.all("unitDataSearchForm:findUnitData").Click

' Another wait as the site is reloading with the results
Do While ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

' Now here is the bit i am stuck at
GetPartNumber = "Ready to get PN!"


EndoftheSub:

Set ie = Nothing
MsgBox (GetPartNumber)

End Function
```

The results page is just a simple table and all i need to grab is the third cell from the second row of it

```
<table id="unitDataSearchForm:outputTable" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="tablebg">
<thead>
<tr><th scope="col">Serial Number</th><th scope="col">Other Data</th><th scope="col">Part Number</th><th scope="col">BLAH</th><th scope="col">BLAHAH</th></tr></thead>
<tbody id="unitDataSearchForm:outputTable:tbody_element">
<tr class="oddRows"><td>XXX123456</td><td>YYYY</td><td>ZZZ-ZZZZZ-ZZ</td><td>SOME TEXT</td><td>BLAHAH</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

The Bit i want is just the ZZZ-ZZZZZ-ZZ so somehow i want GetPartNumber= Row 2, 3rd TD element.. but i have no idea how to get that to output.

The site itself is static so the output page wont change, the table will always be in that format. Ive tried a few methods but nothing seems to work, i only dabble in VBA every now and again so i am far from an expert.

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim htmlObj as HTMLObjectElement 'requires setting a reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Set htmlObj = ie.document.GetElementByID("unitDataSearchForm:outputTable:tbody_element")
GetPartNumber = htmlObj.GetElementsByTagName("TR")(1).Children(2).InnerText
```

By the way this code will have its 1st line always skipped:

```
Do While ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
```

Moreover it doesn't do `ie.Busy` check, it should look like this:

```
Do Until ie.readyState = 4 and IE.Busy = False: DoEvents: Loop
```

Comment: If my solution works, can You also please test if this works?: `GetPartNumber = ie.document.GetElementByID("unitDataSearchForm:outputTable:tbody_element").GetElementsByTagName("TR")(1).Children(2).InnerText`

Comment: Thank you for this, both suggestions worked for me :)

Here is the final code

Comment: GetPartNumber = appIE.document.getElementById("unitDataSearchForm:outputTable").getElementsByTagName("TR")(1).Children(2).innerText          
  I had to remove the ":t‌​body_element" from the code to get it work, but it now runs with no issues